# What's the difference between "dumping" and "jettisoning" fuel?

Tags: faa-regulations, fuel-systems, fuel-dumping

There are some countries (Sweden, for example), they do not permit "dumping" fuel, only "jettisoning" procedures.
Is there any difference according to the amount of fuel that will reach the ground? And the area surrounded by the fuel released?

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/22903/62), maybe a partial dupe?

Comment: OP do you have two accounts? The suggested dupe was asked by someone with the same, uncommon, name as you. I think the previous question should be edited to ask if there are regulatory definitions/differences.

Comment: OP, if you want to regain access to your old account(s), follow the procedure here: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts